# Extending root partition in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, root, boot-partition

How do I extend the partition size of `/dev/sda5` by merging it with unallocated space of 20.0GB

[image]

EDIT:

When I try to create a new partition(using the unallocated space) I get the following error

```
It is not possible to create more than 4 primary partitions
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the space is not allocated, are you prohibited from right-clicking on /dev/sda3 and selecting resize? You could also left-click into the /dev/sda3 space and then click the right-arrow that will illuminate (third from the left).

You should be able to resize and then click on the check to 'apply' changes.

Comment: Nope,  I'm able to resize /dev/sda3 but I'm unable to merge the resulting unallocated partition with /dev/sda5

Comment: I just noticed /dev/sda3 was NTFS. What happens if you try to expand the blue ext4 partition left into the unallocated space?

Comment: All the options to resize/expand /dev/sda4 are freezed

Comment: Are you booted into sda2 or sda3? I bet the partition is mounted. I suspect that if you unmount the partition, you should be able to then re-size accordingly. If you are booted into the partition that you want to resize, you have two options: 1) a live CD on a usb flash drive. 2) Gparted-live, which is like a live CD, but only so that you can resize any of your partitions without having mount or boot from them. Did that make sense?  If you can unmount, type `mount`, find the path, then type `umount` and append the path for /dev/sda3/ Then resize.

Comment: @D75 It's in the screenshot: sda5 is mounted as root. OP should refer to the duplicate question, because it explains how to use a live USB to resize partitions.